# Disable JComboBox pop-up item selection on arrow keys

Tags: java, input, keyboard, jcombobox

I have a very simple desire - I don't want JComboBox respond to arrow key presses. I don't want to select items in the pop-up on arrow keys, or in fact I don't want to show pop-up on pressing down arrow either.

It should be a simple task, but all the threads that I find instead advise people "DON'T DO IT! Don't change default expected behavior! Users will hate you!"

Well, without going into detail - I need it. I have a very specific application that does not require combo-box to respond to arrows. I still need to keep it focused, though.

How do I disable arrow keys? I tried adding a KeyListener, but the box still responds to default key binding.

Thank you.

Comment: *without going into detail* - Please go in to detail. Why should you limit what the user can do? Some users prefer to use the mouse. Others prefer to use the keyboard. If we know why you think you need to do this maybe we can suggest a better solution.